# How to load parquet file to a hive table

Tags: hive, sqoop, parquet

I have done a sqoop import from mysql and got a csv file.
The contents of the file are as below

```
1,KM,Skypark,null,2017-02-21 14:40:49.0,null
2,KM,null,null,2017-02-21 14:40:49.0,null
3,HD,null,null,2017-02-21 14:40:49.0,null
4,AB,SD,USA,2017-02-21 14:40:49.0,null
5,ABa,SaD,US,2017-02-21 14:40:49.0,null
6,DF,SDF,SF,2017-02-21 14:40:49.0,null
7,DF,SDF,SF,2017-02-21 14:41:44.0,null
8,DF,SDF,SF,2017-02-21 14:44:55.0,null
9,DF,SDF,SF,2017-02-21 14:47:59.0,null
```

Now the same sqoop import I have done as parquet file. I got a file with .parquet extension.

I want to create a table using the parquet file. I have tried the following but it gave me different wierd error.

```
create external table test(id int, name string, address string, nation string, date string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as parquet;

load data inpath '/user/XXXXX/test' into table test;
```

How do I get the parquet table to give me exact result as the csv table.

> Say I got a incremental data to the same folder where I stored the previous data. I got records for ID 10 and 11. Now when I load the data from the folder to the parquet table, I am getting the incremental data as first records and then the initial data.

I mean to say the table looks like

```
10 ..............
11 ..............
 1 ..............
 2 ..............
```

Like this I want the first record to be first and incremental data at last

How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need to specify the following statement when you create parquet tables

> row format delimited fields terminated by ','

just specify stored as parquet is enough

```
create external table test(id int, name string, address string, nation string, date string) stored as parquet location '/user/XXXXX/test';
```

Comment: could you please have a look at the question once again I have edited the question